# Google NativeClient on windows : "make (e=5): Access is denied"

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm trying to get Google native client to work on windows and I follow their steps. I installed pepper and while I'm in the getting started folder I type `make serve` but I get a `make (e=5): Access is denied` error...

Here is the whole error message :

```
C:\Users\User123\PROJET C\NaCl\nacl_sdk\pepper_35\getting_started>make serve
C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/tools/make -C part1  all
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:/Users/User123'
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/gett
ing_started/part1'
C:/Users/User123 C:/Users/User123/PROJET C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_3
5/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/n
acl_sdk/pepper_35/toolchain/_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_
tutorial.cc -O2 -IC:/Users/User123 C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/g
etting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/include -LC:/Users/User123 C:/Users/
User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepp
er_35/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:/Users/User123 C:/Users/User123/PROJET C:/Users/V
olt/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/peppe
r_35/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/toolchain/_pnacl/bin/pnacl-
clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_tutorial.cc -O2 -IC:/Users/User123 C:/Users/User123
/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getting_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_3
5/include -LC:/Users/User123 C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getting
_started/part1/C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi,
...) failed.
make (e=5): Access is denied.
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'hello_tutorial.bc' failed
make[1]: *** [hello_tutorial.bc] Error 5
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User123/PROJET C/NaCl/nacl_sdk/pepper_35/getti
ng_started/part1'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'part1_ALL_TARGET' failed
make: *** [part1_ALL_TARGET] Error 2

C:\Users\User123\PROJET C\NaCl\nacl_sdk\pepper_35\getting_started>
```

How could I fix this ? I dont think it comes from files rights...

Answer (score 3):

This looks like its related to the space you have in the name of your folder.  Can you try removing the space?